# YOLO V 5 extract lables from forecast photos

Tags: python, yolo

Good evening with everyone, thank you in advance who will spend his time to answer me! I trained a model with Yolo V5 Master now I need to extract labels from forecast photos to verify the accuracy of my model, how can I do this in Python Ty

I have the prediction of photos from my trained model now I want to derive labels from my photos ty

Comment: You trained it with which library?

Comment: Forgive me, what do you mean by library